# How to drop specific characters in strings in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

How can I drop "-" or double "--" **only** at the beginning of the value in the text column?

```
df <- data.frame (x  = c(12,14,15,178),
                  text = c("--Car","-Transport","Big-Truck","--Plane"))

    x       text
1  12      --Car
2  14 -Transport
3  15  Big-Truck
4 178    --Plane
```

Expected output:

```
    x       text
1  12        Car
2  14  Transport
3  15  Big-Truck
4 178      Plane
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and the following regex `"^\\-+"`. `^` states that the match should be at the beginning of the string, and that it should be 1 or more (`+`) hyphen (`\\-`).

```r
gsub("^\\-+", "", df$text)
# [1] "Car"       "Transport" "Big-Truck" "Plane"
```

If there are whitespaces in the beginning of the string and you want to remove them, you can use `[ -]+` in your regex. It tells to match if there are repeated whitespaces or hyphens in the beginning of your string.

```r
gsub("^[ -]+", "", df$text)
```

---

To apply this to the dataframe, just do this. In `tidyverse`, you can also use `str_remove`:

```r
df$text <- gsub("^\\-+", "", df$text)
# or, in dplyr
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(text1 = gsub("^\\-+", "", text),
         text2 = str_remove(text, "^\\-+"))
```

Comment: and how can I remove the white space?

Comment: Which space? You have no space in your vector

Comment: If it is, lets say : text = c(" -- Car","-Transport","Big-Truck" ," --Plane"))

Comment: See edit. use "^\\s*\\-+"

Comment: @user4567794374545 could you update the question to include this situation?

Comment: I edit a little for a more flexible regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `trimws` to remove certain leading/trailing characters.

```r
trimws(df$text, whitespace = '[ -]')

# [1] "Car"       "Transport" "Big-Truck" "Plane"
```

```r
# a more complex situation
x <- " -- Car - -"

trimws(x, whitespace = '[ -]')
# [1] "Car"
```